# Spring Boot Umlaute in Redirect URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, utf-8, character-encoding

2024 and still problems with encoding UTF-8. Here's my problem reduced to a very simple project with tests (just two important classes, rest is boilerplate created with Spring Initalizr):

https://github.com/kicktipp/springumlaut

I have a redirect in a SpringBoot App which contains an German Umlaut like "ö".

```
@GetMapping("/hallo")
public String hallo() {
    return "redirect:/hallöchen";
}

@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("/hallöchen")
public String helloWithUmlaut() {
    return "Hallöchen";
}
```

Running with the default Tomcat engine I get an status code 400 with the message

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the
> request target [/hall0xc30xb6chen ]. The valid characters are defined
> in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986

The error is thrown in `CoyoteAdapter` in the method convertURI line 1068 and it says in the comment, that this **should never happen**:

```
// Should never happen as B2CConverter should replace
// problematic characters
request.getResponse().sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
```

In my test where I call the URL with Umlaut directly everything works fine.

Why does not Spring Boot encode this URL properly, so everything works out-of-the-box and how can I fix it in the most easy and standard way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [the comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13710#issuecomment-453365174), the literal parts of the redirect URL are not encoded automatically.

For example, you can use [`RedirectAttributes`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) to embed URI variables:

```java
@GetMapping("/hallo")
public String hallo(RedirectAttributes attributes) {
  attributes.addAttribute("var", "hallöchen");
  return "redirect:/{var}";
}
```

or encode it by yourself:

```java
@GetMapping("/hallo")
public String hallo() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  return "redirect:/" + URLEncoder.encode("hallöchen", "UTF-8");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I did understand it now. Would be so nice if everything is utf-8 automatically. so difficult to decide where and when to encode/decode

Comment: I added your solution to the project at github for future reference https://github.com/kicktipp/springumlaut